# Cannot saveAsParquetFile from a RDD of case class

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I follow the instructions in [Spark SQL guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html).

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val people: RDD[Person] = ... 

people.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

And the following is my code:

```
 val rawRDD = sc.textFile(peopleFile).map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt))
```

`Person` here is a `case class`.

When I use

```
rawRDD.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

it causes error:

> Error:(31, 12) value saveAsParquetFile is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Person]
>       rawRDD.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
>              ^

I have already add `import sqlContext.implicits._` ahead before, for **converted to a DataFrame by implicits**.

Why I cannot `saveAsParquetFile from a RDD of case class` here ?

Comment: what is your spark version?

Comment: my spark version is 1.3.0

Answer (score 4):

To convert you must call .toDF() on the RDD.

```
val rawRDD = sc.textFile(peopleFile).map(_.split(",")).map(p => Person(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).toDF()
rawRDD.saveAsParquetFile("people.parquet")
```

The automatic conversion has been removed in 1.3 - see the upgrade comment under http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html :

> Additionally, the implicit conversions now only augment RDDs that are composed of Products (i.e., case classes or tuples) with a method toDF, instead of applying automatically.

Comment: saveAsParquetFile Deprecated (Since version 1.4.0) Use write.parquet(path)